# Generating table for database records

Tags: php, html, database, html-table

The following code will generate `<tr></tr>` on every `$product->title`

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) {
            echo '<tr>
                      <td>'.$product->title.'</td>
                  </tr>';
    }?>
</table>
```

But I want to generate the row after every three columns as output of above code.

```
<table>
    <tr>
            <td>$product->title/td>
            <td>$product->title/td>
            <td>$product->title</td>
    </tr>
            <td>$product->title</td>
            <td>$product->title</td>
            <td>$product->title</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you make a php program count to 3 repeatedly?

Comment: yes, <tr's> should be added after 3 <td's>

Comment: Okay, so do you know how to initialize a variable, add one to it, test to see if it is 3 yet?  If it is, do you know how to cause "</tr> <tr>" to be generated?  If you do, you're just about done.

Answer (score 1):

I use this form so much, that it's committed to type memory.

```
<table>
<?php
    $count = 0;  // we gotta count them lines
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        if ( ($count % 3) == 0 )  // every 3 lines
        {
            if ($count > 0)  // not at first line
                echo '</tr>';  // close previous row
            echo '<tr>';  // open new row
         }
         ++$count;  // better count this one now.

         echo '<td>'.$product->title.'</td>;
    }
    if ($count > 0) 
        echo '</tr>';  // close last row
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @"downvote for not answering the question correctly (where did product->$value come from?)".

It came from a Product class. I added every field of database as a property of class. A method in class makes object of objects when it gets records from database assigning each value to the property. Sorry i don't know much about voting or down-voting i m new here. I just clicked that this was not helpful :P

Answer (score 0):

```
    $i=1;
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) {
           if ( $i<= 3 ) {
               if($i==1) {
                 echo '<tr>';
               }    
               echo '<td>'.$product->title.'</td>';
               $i++;
           }
           else {
               echo'</tr>';
               $i=1;
           }
        }?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
<table>
<?php
   $count = count($products); 
   foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
        // print on first row and third row
        if($key % 3 == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }
        echo '<td>'.$product->title.'</td>';
        // print on third row or on last element
        if((($key + 1) % 3 == 0 && $key > 0) || $key == $count-1) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
   }
?>
</table>
```

If you array isn't indexed from 0 and up you would have to use a counter for the `$key` variable.